# How to check disk read or write utilization

Tags: linux, disk, utilization, iostat

I want to know disk read / write utilization
especially, only read or write utilization or write utilization 
I tried using iostat but it shows entire utilization,

How to check only disk read or only write utilization (The progress is consist of read + write works)

Comment: Are you looking for that ? -> cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-disk-performance-monitoring-howto.html or have you tried that? -> http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I progress the work (such that sometime read and  some times write, read and write are mixed) then how to check only read util or write util?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `iotop` is the right tool for you.

On the left you can see which process causes how much load and the `hdparm` test I ran in the session on the right is clearly shown there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I progress the work (such that sometime read and  some times write, read and write are mixed) then how to check only read util or write util?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get the result in a graphical format then go with munin monitoring tool  http://munin-monitoring.org/    It provide graphical information about Disk IO per device, Disk latency per device, Disk utilization and Disk throughput.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I progress the work (such that sometime read and  some times write, read and write are mixed) then how to check only read util or write util?